# From time domaine to frequency domain

Tags: matlab, filter, fft, lowpass-filter

I have a problem in my MATLAB program. I'm trying to find a cutoff frequency to create a low pass filter for compass data. I'm trying to go from the time domain to the frequency domain and find an `Fc`, so I used the FFT but it seems that's it's nor working.

This is what i have done:

```
dataset=xlsread('data.xlsx','Feuil1','A1:A751');
t=1:length(dataset);
z=abs(fft(dataset));
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(dataset)
title('dataNonFiltrer')
subplot(2,2,4)
plot(z)
title('frequenciel')
```

And i get this wish seems to be not correct:

[image]

Comment: "Not correct" What did you expect to see? You've successfully plotted the output of the FFT, if that is not what you expected to see, then please share your expectation so we point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for editing my Message and thanks for respond, i'm expecting to see a peak in the frequency domaine... in about 100 hz but i see here is a peak in 0 whish mean that it's not correct and also on the frequency the y axis should be in the frequency domain but it's still on the time domain [0,400] so i'm just a little confused . sorry for my english... :)

Comment: First thing I would check is has the data been read properly from the 'data.xlsx' file, perhaps even plot it in Excel and see if the plots match. It seems like you are trying to read 751 values in from the file but when you plot it in MatLab, the x-axis runs from 0 to ~375, I'd have thought there should be ~751 values on that plot but maybe Im missing something.

Comment: The peak at 0 is the DC component.

Comment: You are not plotting it right BTW. Check the documentation to see how you need to plot the fft componets. For example, note that it is symetric

Comment: sorry it's my bad normally i'm reading from 1 to 363. i'll modify the code. but we still have the same problem

Comment: You need to read more about FFT, the output is not in frequecy directly.

Comment: The peak at 0 is the sum of your signal (DC component, as DukeOfMarmalade said). The second peak from the left if your expected peak. It's location along the x-axis is the integer value `k` from the DFT. How that translates to actual frequencies depends on your sampling frequency, as indicated by Ander in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just not plotting the data right.

To plot the `fft` of a signal `X`, do ([from the docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html)):

```
Fs = 1000;   % Sampling frequency of your data. YOU NEED TO KNOW THIS, change             

L = length(X);             % Length of signal
Y = fft(X);
P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
plot(f,P1) 
title('frequenciel X(t)')
xlabel('f (Hz)')
ylabel('|P1(f)|')
```